# Printing a Multiplication Table Using Python Nested For Loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiplication

```
for i in range(3,33,3):
    for j in range(1,11,1):
        print("3 *", j, '=', i)
    if j == 10:
       break
```

This is the output that I am getting:

```
3 * 1 = 3                                                                                                                                                          
3 * 2 = 3                                                                                                                                                          
3 * 3 = 3                                                                                                                                                          
3 * 4 = 3                                                                                                                                                          
3 * 5 = 3                                                                                                                                                          
3 * 6 = 3                                                                                                                                                          
3 * 7 = 3                                                                                                                                                          
3 * 8 = 3                                                                                                                                                          
3 * 9 = 3                                                                                                                                                          
3 * 10 = 3
```

Could anyone please point out the error for me?

Comment: Why do you need the `if` statement, the `for` loop stops when it gets to 10 automatically.

Comment: You're not multiplying anything.

Comment: you don't need two loops.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `i` to `i * j`:

```
for i in range(3,33,3):
    for j in range(1,11,1):
        print("3 *", j, '=', i * j)
    if j == 10:
        break
```

Here is a simplified version:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(f"3 * {i} = {3 * i}")
```

Output:

```
3 * 1 = 3
3 * 2 = 6
3 * 3 = 9
3 * 4 = 12
3 * 5 = 15
3 * 6 = 18
3 * 7 = 21
3 * 8 = 24
3 * 9 = 27
3 * 10 = 30
```

Comment: I got the answer, people! Thanks to everyone who helped! Oh, Happy New Year, btw!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print multiples of `3`, you don't need two loops. Just one loop from 1 to 10, and then multiply that by 3.

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    j = i * 3
    print('3 *', i, '=', j)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want the product as well as the multiplier, you can use enumerate for this. The code will look something like this:

```
for i,j in enumerate(range(3,33,3)):
    print("3 *", i, '=', j)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing nested loops*, but you meant to loop in parallel. You can do that with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for i, j in zip(range(3, 33, 3), range(1, 11)):
    print("3 *", j, '=', i)
```

Output:

```
3 * 1 = 3
3 * 2 = 6
3 * 3 = 9
3 * 4 = 12
3 * 5 = 15
3 * 6 = 18
3 * 7 = 21
3 * 8 = 24
3 * 9 = 27
3 * 10 = 30
```

Canonical question: [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1663807/4518341)

* This creates a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), but it's cut short by the `break`.

---

However, in this case it's simpler to just do the math, like in [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65525915/4518341).